# How to send app to background after finishing activity which is started from push notification

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, back-stack, activity-stack

I have an activity which is called if the app receives a push notification. The activity is started with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. The activity, let's call it 'A' shows UI and finishes after a while. In this point have a problem with activity stack.

Scenario:

1. The app is in the background with another activity 'B'
2. Then the app receives a push notification and starts Activity A.
3. After related things done, the app finishes Activity A
4. Then returns to Activity B and stays in the foreground even the app was in the background before the push notification is received.

After debugging, I figured out that the system calls `onResume` method of Activity B after finishing Activity A.
How can I do the app keep staying in background if the app started from background? Should I change intent flags of the activity A?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514868/how-to-send-application-to-background

Comment: Don't think so. I'm not looking for catching home key or sending the app background via another intent.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure it'll work since I never tried it, but have you tried changing to FLAG_NEW_TASK and FLAG_CLEAR_TASK? The first one creates the activity as a new task (even if you already have another activity stack on background), and the second destroys the previous stack.

Comment: Have you tried `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);`

Comment: @RicardoCosteira adding FLAG_CLEAR_TASK flag sends the app to the background but the problem is the app cannot continue the recent activity of the app after tapping in the recent apps screen. After finishing Acvitiy A and resuming the app from recent app screen, the app shows the initial screen.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can achieve this in two ways

1- From manifest file with activity tag `android:noHistory="true"`

2- From code when you are staring the activity set flags like below

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, Youractivity.class); 
mIntent.setFlags(mIntent.getFlags() | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

For more information checkout [developers link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)

One other thing you can do is instead of `this.finish()` in notificationActivity is to use `this.finishAffinity();`. This will close the app instead coming to foreground.

Comment: It didn't work either since I'm already finishing the activity that raised after push notification.